# Aliases in Bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, alias

In the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html#Aliases) regarding Aliases in Bash there is a statement:

> The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is checked to see
>   if it has an alias

What is "simple command" and "first word of a simple command" in that context? Some examples?

Answer (score 3):

Meaning of the term `simple command` is explained in the [same manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Commands.html#Simple-Commands) you linked to but in the different section:

> A simple command is the kind of command encountered most often. It's
>   just a sequence of words separated by blanks, terminated by one of the
>   shell's control operators (see Definitions). The first word generally
>   specifies a command to be executed, with the rest of the words being
>   that command's arguments.